# Hunt down [software-hunting]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, clean-up

[software-hunting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-hunting) has 5 questions, no followers, and no wiki.

It is used on questions soliciting software recommendations.

Given that this is off-topic, can we burninate this tag?

Here are the questions using this tag:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103225
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106923
- [What are Good Libraries for a Map Feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183866)
- [Build automation tools, pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119065)
- [Create PDF from word document from desktop application using C++ or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054139)

Downvotes, close votes and delete votes for everybody!

Comment: Do it!​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Extra credit: cast a close vote for the 3 open questions with this tag.

Comment: Done and Done :)

Comment: Oh @AlexisKing .. couldn't resist, could you?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling What could you *possibly* be talking about??? :o

Comment: @will I flagged for clossing on the ones that were still open

Comment: Now we have a list of the offenders.  Downvote, VTC and VTD away!

Comment: @Will Thanks - I was just getting ready to do that.

Comment: Wow, that tag was DUSTY!  All questions were '09 or earlier.

Comment: @Will Pulled that last one, since it was a dup.

Comment: Ha. A downvote. I love it.

Comment: Someone apparently hate going hunting...

Comment: How about `Shoot [software-hunting]`?

Comment: Is it not [software-hunting] season?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the questions with that tag are closed / deleted and the tag has been removed from all the questions. The tag is now burninated!

[image]